# SharePoint 2013 Site Home Page Title Formatting

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I created a sub-site in SharePoint 2013 and added my custom logo to the page. For some reason I cannot change the size or color of the title of the Home page. I can't use a Web Part to create a new title because the old one cannot be removed from the page. It's a small font just right of the Lefthand Quick Launch menu.
I go to: Site Settings | Look and Feel | Look and Feel Title, description, and logo, but it give no option to change the font color or size.
Is SP 2013 just counter intuitive or am I an idiot?

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much how it will work, so don't break your head over it.

If you only want to change 1 element's look and feel you have 2 choices.

1. Edit the v15.master page. *This is a bad idea, unless you have played with master files before. Read a lot before venturing forth in master pages.*
2. Edit the CSS file. This is a lot better idea simply because it is easier to roll back.

**Both of these will affect all pages that use these files.**

So how do you do this then?
[image: SharePoint page Title code behind]

See the class listed for the Title.

```
class="ms-core-pageTitle"
```

We need to edit this in your main CSS file for your theme.

[image: SharePoint CSS files]

If you decide to wade in here you must look for the CSS that contains this class, I would pick

```
/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css
```

You can edit this with SPD or any text editor, note the path I used is in the 15 hive on the server.

I open \\spserver\c$\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable\COREV15.CSS

There you will find the following section

```
.ms-core-pageTitle
{  
font-size:2.77em;
white-space:nowrap;
color:pink; /*Let us test colour*/
font-size:9.77em;/*make it huge*/
/*You edits here*/
}
```

Save, F5 and be amazed.